# WooCommerce display variable product attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I am trying to display attributes of a particular product (i.e. id: 459) that has multiple variations and trying to display some of the attributes (i.e. name, id, link to the product and image) on the index page. I managed to get the variation image and id, however now trying to find it difficult to display the URL to the product and display variable product name.

I tried to look on the net for an answer but couldn't find it even codex or documentation. Can someone please help?

This is my working code, showing the image and id perfectly fine.

```
<?php 
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( '459' );
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
    echo "<img src=" . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .">";
    echo $variation['variation_id'];
    echo $variation['variation_Name ']; // (Error: "Notice: Undefined index: variation_Name in   /var/www/wp-content/themes/...")
}                    
?>
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

**EDIT**
This is my code, everything works perfectly apart from not getting the attribute name.

I am getting this error message: Array to string conversion in /var/www/wp-content

```
<?php 
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( '459' ); 
$variations = $product->get_available_variations(); 

foreach ( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute_name =>   $ {
 $attributes[] = array( 'name' => ucwords( str_replace( 'attribute_', '', 
wc_attribute_taxonomy_slug( $attribute_name ) ) ), 
'option' => $attribute, ); 
echo $attribute;
}

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) { 

echo '<div class="col-3">';
echo '<a href="'.$product->get_permalink().'#variations-table">';

echo $product->get_title();

echo "<img src=" . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .">";

echo 'View Product</a>';
echo '</div>';

} 

?>
```

Thank you soo much :)

Comment: foreach ( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute_name => $attribute ) 
{ 

$attributes[] = array( 'name' => ucwords( str_replace( 'attribute_', '', wc_attribute_taxonomy_slug( $attribute_name ) ) ), 'option' => $attribute, );
} 
print_r($attributes);

Comment: your code is not proper i think

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I am unable to rectify the issue. Can you please help to inspect the code and help? I am not too familer with the Woocommerce and also trying to recitify the issue. Thank you soo much, really appreciate it :)

Comment: I found another method, to replace '_' slugname with the spaces and capitalize the name. Hopefully this will rectify the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* try this below code instead*/
/* Get variation attribute based on product ID */
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
$var_data = [];
foreach ($variations as $variation) {
if($variation[‘variation_id’] == $variation_id){
$var_data[] = $variation[‘attributes’];
}
}

/*Get attributes from loop*/
foreach($var_data[0] as $attrName => $var_name) {
echo $var_name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It's giving the following error message `Undefined variable: variation_id`, `Undefined offset: 0 ` and ` Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. Can you please help to resolve? Thank you

Comment: no need to add this if($variation[‘variation_id’] == $variation_id) condition if you are sure that you have variable product 459 , please try after remove this condition

Comment: Thank you I removed it, I am still unable to get the Variable Name and Link to the Product. I can only get the image of the variable product. It's giving the error: `Undefined offset: 0` and `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. Thank you.

Comment: `<?php 
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( '459' );
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();`

Comment: `$var_data = [];
foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
    echo "<img src=" . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .">";

}`

Comment: `/*Get attributes from loop*/
foreach($var_data[0] as $attrName => $var_name) {
    echo $var_name;
    } ?>` This is my code now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: $product = new WC_Product_Variable( '459' ); 
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();  
$var_data = []; 
foreach ( $variations as $variation ) { 
   $var_data[] = $variation['attributes'];    
          
}
/*Get attributes from loop*/ 
foreach($var_data[0] as $attrName => $var_name) { 
    echo $var_name;    
 }
/* this updated code from myend */

Comment: this above code will print all attribute names only

Comment: Thank you soo much, it seems to be giving 'slug' (name_name_name) name rather than the variable name and it's on displaying the very first slug name and not all. Sorry for the trouble, can you please help further :)?

Comment: Howmany variation you have in your product?

Comment: for the product id 459, I have 8 variable products that needs to be displayed. Thank you :)

Comment: I am able to get images of all 8 variable products, it's just that i am strugging with displaying their names and url.

Comment: for image you can use this function to retrive img tag with all $image_tag = $variation->get_image();

Comment: I get the image, can you please help how i can get the variation name please? I am struggling with it only. Thank you :)

Comment: yes, it's giving the name of the main product containing the id. Not the variations names. Thank you :)

Comment: in woocommerce if there is one product which have multiple variation then it is just variation of attributes only but variation product name is same for all

Comment: I missunderstood the theory of Woocommerce, maybe my question was wrong. Thank you soo much for your help. How can I get the attribute name of the variable product please?

Comment: // variation attributes
   foreach ( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute_name => $attribute ) {

    // taxonomy-based attributes are prefixed with `pa_`, otherwise simply `attribute_`
    $attributes[] = array(
     'name'   => ucwords( str_replace( 'attribute_', '', wc_attribute_taxonomy_slug( $attribute_name ) ) ),
     'option' => $attribute,
    );
   }

Comment: Thank you soo much for all your help. Appreciate it very much, it's still not working for me. Let me post the code in the answer. So it makes its eaiser for you. Thank you :)

Comment: I have updated my question above, please see EDIT ANSWER. Thank you and sorry my php and knowledge with woocommerce is not very well. Thank you :)